# How to pass multiple values to one parameter outside the macro def in ant build

Tags: ant, parameters, build, macrodef

[How to pass multiple parameters to a target in Ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552646/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-a-target-in-ant)

A macrodef is defined as shown below:

```xml
<macrodef name="execEtlBinScript">
   <attribute name="script" />
   <attribute name="resultproperty" />
   <sequential>
      <exec executable="@{script}" resultproperty="@{resultproperty}" />
   </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

We will be passing the values like this to the above macrodef:

```
<execEtlBinScript script="somescript" resultproperty="status1" />
```

But, can I pass like this?

```
<execEtlBinScript script="somescript, other script" resultproperty="status1, status2" />
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the actual problem with sample reproducible build script?

Comment: @Rao Example:
<macrodef name="execEtlBinScript">
    <attribute name="script" />
    <attribute name="resultproperty" />
    <sequential>
        <exec executable="@{script}" resultproperty="@{resultproperty}"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef> 
We will be passing the values like this:

<execEtlBinScript script="somescript" resultproperty="status1" />

Can i passlike this?

<execEtlBinScript script="somescript, other script" resultproperty="status1, status2" />

Comment: I wanted to pass multiple values to the same parameter in one line

Comment: Got your question. But that depends on the `exec` task that you are calling and it is not specified in your script. You may pass if that task supports. Do you mind to show what that task is ?

Comment: <target name="logs">
      <macro_launch_jvm target="someTarget"   />
   </target>
  
  <macrodef name="macro_custom"  >
   <attribute name ="target"/>
      
   <sequential> 
            
                             <classpath>
                              <pathelement location="${ant.home}/lib/ant-launcher.jar" />
                             </classpath>                              
                                 <arg value="@{target}"/>                              
                             </java>
                  
     </sequential>  
     </macrodef>

Comment: <macro_launch_jvm target="someTarget , otherTarget"   />
I wanted to pass more than 1 value to target parameter so that in the macro definition it can take all the targets one by one.    Basically it creates a log file for each target.

Comment: Let us assume if a programme requires a string as input to process it successfully. But it may not like to take multiple value. If it needs to be handled to take list of values separated by commas, the programme has to be modified accordingly. Similarly, check if you task can such input. It is not clear from the sample you provided.

Comment: Hi Rao, Thanks for your reply. I think the class which i am using may not allow to pass multiple values. I tried to do that but its taking them as 1 value.